# Problems in Tortoise SVN Merging between Trunk and branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-merge

I am new to Tortoise SVN and i have the following 2 doubts

i)When i checkout Trunk Project from Repository,Head Revision is 181 ,whereas when i checkout ,it says Workingcopy revision as 204(yes it shows a Different revision)
when i see Properties I am able to see the following Revision

[image]

Is this expected one ?

ii)When i try to Merge branch(Rev:202) with trunk(Rev:181),to commit the changes from branch to Trunk,There are some conflicts which when i try to mark as "Resolve Conflict using mine"

It shows the error as follows

[image]

Both Trunk and branch are present in the Same Repository.
Not sure what i am missing .

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: When you checked out `Ironman_Magnetor_Trial4`, while the entire repository may be at revision 204, the second line `last commit revision` is referring to the last time **this** directory was modified.

For your second question, tree conflicts are usually a result of folders being renamed/moved. I'm not exactly sure what you meant by

> Both Trunk and branch are present in the nearby location.

This doesn't make a ton of sense. Do you mean you have both the trunk and the branch checked out on your computer? If so, that shouldn't be an issue as long as they're checked out in different paths. Right click on the folder giving you trouble, **TortoiseSVN** > **Check For Modifications**. You should be able to resolve the conflicts from this window.

Comment: For Second Question ,I meant Both Trunk and branch directories are present in the Same Repository in SVN